# Is there software that will turn image into a combination of squares?

Tags: gimp

I am working on a design where I would like to change a particular image into a combination of squares and rectangles to form a shape that resembles it.

For example, lets take a look at the following cat image:

[image]

Although pretty sloppy, I was wondering if there is any software out there that would transform any drawing or image into something like what is shown below?:

[image]

Thank you for the help in advance! :)

Comment: Welcome on GD.SE, Jakub. Can you tell us something more about your efforts? Have you tried to combine Gimp [mosaic filter](https://docs.gimp.org/2.6/en/plug-in-mosaic.html) with the [bucket fill](https://docs.gimp.org/en/gimp-tool-bucket-fill.html)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps the simplest way to create such a combination of boxes is using both **Gimp** and **Inkscape**.

Open the image in Gimp and use the [mosaic filter](https://docs.gimp.org/2.6/en/plug-in-mosaic.html)

[image: Gimp Mosaic filter]

Configure the filter to use square tiles and remove other effects:

[image: Gimp Mosaic filter configuration]

Instead of using the [bucket fill](https://docs.gimp.org/en/gimp-tool-bucket-fill.html) to isolate the areas, a faster way is open the mosaic image in Inkscape and [trace the bitmap](http://tavmjong.free.fr/INKSCAPE/MANUAL/html/Trace.html):

[image: Inkscape bitmap trace]

[Ungroup](http://tavmjong.free.fr/INKSCAPE/MANUAL/html/Groups.html) the result of bitmap tracing, [enable snapping](https://www.tutorviacomputer.com/inkscape/inkscape-snapping/) to nodes and draw [rectangles](http://tavmjong.free.fr/INKSCAPE/MANUAL/html/Shapes-Rectangles.html):

[image: The rectangle snaps to nodes]

It's a very simple operation:

[image: Resulting image]